# How to Dockerize a two nodejs applications in one directory

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a directory structure like this:
[image: Directory Structure]

I've never used Docker before and want to dockerize my application, the backend folder is a node app with its own `package.json` and the frontend folder is its own node app with a `package.json`, normally to launch my app in my dev environment I start it with two separate terminals, I also have a `config.js` file in the backend and frontend directory with environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would use them in two containers.
You can just create a `dockerfile` in each folder and create a new docker image for each folder/service.

Once you have the images ready you can use e.g. docker-compose to start your containers. Each container can get the same volume to the config file so that each container can read the same config file.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/
https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Jens